# How to create new tools in PencilKit

Tags: swift, pencilkit

By default, Apple gives us three inking tools: .pen, .pencil, and .marker.
How can I create a new tool? Specifically, I need a ballpen tool that has a constant width.

Apple has created new tools for PencilKit in their Freeform app, take a look: [image: here]

Or non-Apple Prodrafts app even has a scroll view of tools: [image: here]

Thanks for any hints in advance.

Comment: Apple has access to private APIs, so the fact that they can achieve something doesn't mean that it is also achievable in 3rd party apps using public APIs.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was available in a beta version. Unfortunately they removed it for 3d party apps. They did the same thing with shape and text recognition

I think one new ink type was called micron. I can’t find it anymore…

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).